# Should Class I electric devices be connected to unearthed sockets?

Tags: safety

I rent an old house and most of the power sockets do not have earth/ground. I need to connect Class I devices (such as laptop chargers, full PC towers, soldering irons) which require an earth to operate safely. Some even indicate "Do not connect to unearthed outlet".

I understand that the proper solution is to add earth to existing sockets, but the landlord told me this is not required by regulations for old houses, so they will not do it. They only provide earthed sockets in the kitchen.

**Given that the unearthed sockets are protected by an RCD (residual current device), if I decide to connect Class I appliances to them, what is the risk to human life and equipment?**

I know that an RCD cannot substitute proper grounding (as the 20ms that it takes for the device to react can be enough to stop a human heart), but I'm trying to evaluate the extent of the risk.

To pre-empt some proposals: I've checked the sockets' back plates, and they're not grounded, so there's no easy fix. Also, using the kitchen's earthed sockets to connect a long extension is too cumbersome a fix.

Comment: Some equipment use the earth ground as part of the EMI control scheme, so that is another thing to be aware of. For example, an equipment can have 2 Y caps to earth ground. Also as an example, you mentioned soldering iron, that could be quite problematical. Imagine the iron floats to a voltage half the line voltage and you touch that to a component that has a return path to "ground".

Comment: I am going to tell you what I would do in your specific situation. This is not advice. I am not telling you what you should do. Given that the outlets ARE protected by the RCD, I would plug my equipment in and use it. If any of my equipment caused the RCD to trip, I would not use that equipment any more. If you don't mind the expense and you are in the US, you could also replace the outlets with GFCI outlets for convenience. Remove them when you move out. Outside the US, you can do the same if such are available.

Comment: Thanks for the input! 
@rioraxe, maybe for soldering I should short the floating ground (iron's tip, socket's ground pin etc) to a pad on which I sit the components. Then I risk shock to myself though.

Comment: @mkeith, I decided to go that direction for short term. After weeks that I could not use my tv/tower pc, and after having the electrician almost make fun of me for requiring ground, I went ahead and plugged stuff in. Soon enough, I got lightly shocked by touching the ground pin. Meter shows 75V, but it's not a reliable one (cheap). I don't dare touch it again...   Of course all this is at my own risk (the landlord's actually), you made it clear :)

Answer (score 2):

In the US, the National Electric Code allows replacement of 2 pin sockets with 3 pin GFCI outlets with the ground unconnected.  They must be labeled as such, but they are considered safe for use with equipment with a 3 prong plug.  You could make the assumption then that a GFCI outlet with a 2 to 3 prong adapter with the ground unconnected might also be considered safe, but it's advisable to connect the ground as well: (Note that EMI may be an issue with no real ground, but the section below deals with safety.)

Replacing Receptacles to Meet the NEC

[Link](http://www.mikeholt.com/news/archive/html/master/recept2wire.htm)

The NEC requires receptacles installed on 15 and 20 ampere branch circuits to be of the grounding-type and it requires the grounding contacts of those receptacles to be effectively grounded to the branch circuit equipment grounding conductor [210-7]. However, the Code allows the installation of any of the following installations when replacing a 2-wire nongrounding-type receptacle where no ground exists in the outlet box [210-7(d)(3)], Figure 9/10:

(a) Replace the 2-wire receptacle with another 2-wire receptacle.

(b) Replace the 2-wire receptacle with a GFCI-type receptacle and marked the receptacle with the words “No Equipment Ground.”

(c) Replace the 2-wire receptacle with a grounding-type receptacle where protected by a GFCI protection device (circuit breaker or receptacle). Since the grounding terminals for the receptacles are not grounded, the receptacles must be marked with the words “GFCI Protected” and “No Equipment Ground.”

A grounding-type receptacle that is GFCI protected without an equipment grounding conductor is a safer installation than a grounding-type receptacle with an equipment grounding conductor (if GFCI protection is not provided). This is because the GFCI protection device will clear a ground-fault when the fault-current is 5 milliamperes (+ or – 1 milliampere), which is less than the current level necessary to cause serious electric shock or electrocution, Figure 10/11.

A grounding-type receptacle without a ground is a safe installation as long as the GFCI protection circuitry within the device has not failed from shorts and voltage transients. To insure proper GFCI protection, test the GFCI monthly in accordance with the manufactures instructions and if the GFCI test does not operate properly, replace the GFCI protection device.

Comment: The OP's reference to an "RCD" suggests to me that he isn't in North America.

Comment: Thanks for the write-up @John D. I am in Europe (Netherlands), but I trust US regulation is at par. From what I understand, my installation fulfills option (c) already. But I do not understand your initial remark about the assumption I may make. 

Having a 3-prong receptacle installed in the wall, connected to a circuit that is GFCI protected, while the receptacle's ground  is not connected: is this considered ok under NEC, to plug 3-prong possibly Class I devices?

Comment: In the US, we have a situation. There are many old outlets with polarized ungrounded outlets. The NEC did not want to forbid people from replacing such outlets with GFCI outlets, because replacing them with GFCI is an improvement in safety. So, it is OK to replace ungrounded outlet with GFCI in such a case. But it is NOT OK for any new construction or remodel. I am not a code expert, but this is my understanding.

Comment: I am trying to understand if there's a difference between a 3-prong socket installed on a 2-wire GFCI protected circuit and a 3 prong GFCI protected socket installed on a 2-wire otherwise unprotected circuit.

Comment: Probably offtopic but possibly of interest: I just tested the centrally-installed GFCI and it doesn't look like it works. Sparks, circuit breaker tripped, but GFCI still up. Sad...

Comment: Note that one of the reasons to mark them is that surge protectors (often used with computers and TVs!) will not work - they rely on the ground to shunt current from the devices. So, the GFI will protect you, but a lightning strike may fry your equipment even if you think they are protected by the surge suppressor.

Answer (score 1):

This isn't the best arrangement, but you could use one of the "cheater plugs" that plugs into a 2-pin socket but provides a 3-pin socket *as long as you actually connect the ground lead to ground*.

All cheater plugs I've seen come with either a short ground lead, usually green, or with a "O" lug that is meant to go onto the screw holding the cover plate in place.  The latter is iffy at best.  However, either kind lets you run a longer wire and connect the ground pin to ground.

You said this house is old, so probably has metal pipes, and the pipe system goes into the ground somewhere.  If so, any metal pipe will be well grounded.  Run a decent size wire at least large enough for whatever current the breaker is rated for from the cheater plug to the nearest copper pipe.  Clean off a ring around the pipe with a wire brush or sandpaper.  It should look like shiny copper.  Then you can get any of a variety of clamps meant to go around pipes like that, and clamp the wire securely to the pipe.  Solder the other end to the ground lug or ground lead coming out of the cheater plug.

Make sure to test this before using it.  Probably the best thing for you to do at your apparent level of electrical savy is to get a commercial outlet tester.  These are now commonly available at hardware stores, home improvement stores, and of course on line.

Comment: Thanks Olin, I think this is the most realistic solution, given that I was just mildly shocked by touching the floating ground. I'll give it more thought and accept at a later time.